# Error Inserting information at InnoDB tables

Tags: c#, mysql, innodb

We trying to insert some information at InnoDB table of MySQL Server and retrieve last is of this insert.

The problem is: we got the last id, but the information dont be inserted at table...

some information that could help:

- We tryed to update mysql.data;
- We tryed to update ADO.NET Driver for MySQL (Connector/NET);
- When we try to insert MyISAM table works;
- We tryed to insert with the same query at another server in InnoDB table and works;
- We tryed to drop the InnoDB table and creat another one InnoDB table, execute the same query and doesn't work;
- We tryed to execute the same query at WorkBench and works, but from application doesn't work.

MySQLServer: 5.6

Creat Statement of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `TBimportacao` (
`Id`int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`idLogin` int(10) NOT NULL,
`CNPJ` varchar(40) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`NomeArquivo` varchar(500) COLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
`Progresso` varchar(5) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
`Label` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
`TamanhoArquivos` varchar(10) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT '1',
`ArquivoAtual` varchar(10) COLLATE latin1_general_ci default '1',
`Concluido` tinyint(1) default '0',
`Erro` text COLLATE latin1_general_ci,
`DataImport` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`RemoverVisualizar` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY ('Id')
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;
```

**Insert Query:**

```
INSERT INTO `database`.`TBimportacao`
(idLogin, NomeArquivo, CNPJ, Progresso, Label, TamanhoArquivos, ArquivoAtual, Concluido, Erro, DataImport, RemoverVisualizar)
VALUES ('2321', 'arquivo', '512315213', '', 'Processando...', '', '', 0, '', '2018-06-26 16:18:58', '0');
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you did not issue `COMMIT`??

What was the value of `autocommit`?  Was there a `BEGIN` or `START TRANSACTION` before the `INSERT`?

Comment: We use this connection class in anothers tables at the same MySQL Server, some tables has MyISam engine and works, but when I try to insert in an InnoDB table, doesn't work, but the most curious is that don't insert the row, but retrieve the LastID.

Comment: @RichardAndrade - Learn about "transactions" and "commit".  The lecture is too long to give in this context.